# How to setup and host Silverlight application with data access

Tags: asp.net, silverlight, hosting

I have the following requirements for app I want to write just for fun:

- I want to design the UI in Silverlight.
- The app must then be hosted online somewhere
- I need the app to serve data to users, and to save user input server-side

I know WPF quite well, but I have never written anything to go online. I don't know where to start! Most "Getting Started with Silverlight" tutorials cover the basics of XAML etc. What I need to know is more related to how do I host this thing and set it up to read and write server-side data. Please tell me which technologies I require and suggest resources where applicable.
To generalize my question somewhat:

1. What is the simplest path for me to host a silverlight app online?
2. What technologies do I need if I want to read and write server-side data based on user input? I would prefer the data in a SQLite database or a XML file.

I just want to stress this point - I don't require enterprise solutions. The data involved is MINIMAL, and the user base is 10 or 20 people.

Answer (score 0):

To start with enable Internet Information Services as part of your Windows setup (it tends not to be included as part of the default install). Set a default website within it that points to your project directory (actually you can also set this from within Visual Studio).

Data source depends on hosting site and what they provide, but if you write a decent data layer  interface your business logic can be data source agnostic.

By doing this you can test your code in a more relevent environment, locally on your machine, before you then go and select your website host (who incidentally will have to be able to cope with Silverlight).

Answer (score 0):

Hosting silverlight is quite easy, xap its just a renamed zip file and if there is required html silverlight will work pretty automatically on clients.

As for data - most popular way is to use WCF services currently. If you host both silverlight application and WCF service on single domain there will be no cross domain problems.

Just start with creating a Silverlight project in visual studio. As for question 1. - hosting silverlight is very easy, most (if not all) asp.net hostings currently support silverlight.

You just need html code with object tag pointing to xap. Rest is clients browser job.

Comment: So I need to get a hosting service that supports ASP.NET, and then I can just upload the Silverlight app and my data? Do I need a seperate ASP.NET application to provide the data access?

Comment: couple of options here, wcf service is also hosted in ASP.NET and it can be part of your single website with html front end, silverlight and wcf service. Or it can be more separate like asp.net site and WCF service application somewhere else (you will most likely be satisfied with first approach). WCF hosting is also everywhere I believe where ASP.NET is, but hosting WCF service (setting up) can be harder if thats not naturally supported by hosting providers. (there are many steps before WCF starts working but if you follow MS guide it will start working eventually).